# CSS cascade order in Header

Tags: html, css, header, cascading

Is there a way to force a css link to a file to be the one that is used without relying on cascading order to determine what gets overwritten?

I am using a CMS where I can add new css links but cannot change the cascading order in the header tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="old.css" type="text/css" />
```

I need "new.css" to overide "old.css" without overwriting the code of old.css. I do not have access to simply change the order of the header code, I so wish I could!

Comment: Do you have access in the old.css? Can you edit it?

Comment: yes I do, I just can't edit the order in the header code

Answer (score 0):

There's no way what you're looking for.

Your last stylesheet would override the previous stylesheet rules.

---

But if you can use javascript or jquery then you may shift the order like this:

jQuery:

```
$('link[ref="old.css"]').insertBefore($('link[ref="new.css"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can if you make the selector more specific. You can do this by simply adding "body" before the actual selector.

Example:

```
.button {
color: blue;
}
```

Would be ignored by using

```
body .button {
 color: green;
}
```

Quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cbs5por/

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS allows you to add new CSS links, it should be smart enough to put the new one the bottom. If it's putting it on the top and you don't want to mess with jQuery, you can just copy the content from the "old.css" and paste that into the "new.css" file and vise-versa. That way you'll have the correct content in the bottom file which will override the top link.